# Does wire brought into the house have to immediately enter a box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

I need to bring in a new 220v circuit to my basement. Once the conduit enters the basement does it need to immediately enter a box like this diagram or can I just continue the wire to outlet box 20’ away.

[image]

Comment: Is this a service wire (first off the meter), a feeder (going to a subpanel), or a simple circuit like for an EVSE or welder or receptacle?

Comment: Just an outlet for a dryer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The box is only *required* if you're making a connection just inside the wall. For example, you're pulling THHN/THWN *wires* through the conduit, but you want to run NM-B *cable* through the walls. In that case the junction between the cables *must* be in a junction box. If you're continuing with THHN in conduit (through your walls or surface mounted), *and* you have a continuous run there's no requirement for the box at all. Note that if you've hit the end of your spool of wire and need to join to a new spool, you'll need to make that connection in a JB, no matter what.

If you're simply changing direction, a box, another LB or even a sweep (if there's room in the wall) could be used. As a matter of fact, the short stub of EMT coming out of the LB in the picture could be replaced with a sweep elbow that immediately turns the wire in the direction you need to go. It *may* not be the easiest pull, but with the LB right there, it shouldn't be difficult.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not an electrician. This is based off of knowledge gleaned from reading and applying common sense, not an in-depth knowledge of the NEC.

Comment: What if I strip just enough NM-B sheathing to run from inside the house to the breaker box right outside?

Comment: @TonySmith A) I appreciate the check-mark, but I'd wait a bit longer. Make sure that none of the electricians here see any errors in what I've said - that's based mostly on my reading of other answer and some common sense, not an in depth knowledge of code (shoulda put that disclaimer in my answer.). B) Nope, can't do that - you _cannot_ (I know this one for _certain_!) strip the sheath off cables to pull through conduit. They're neither properly insulated nor are they properly marked for that purpose.

Comment: Well, OK, you _can_, _technically_ do it, but it doesn't meet code and is illegal . If discovered after a fire (or other insurance claim), your insurance company could use it as an excuse to not pay the claim.

Comment: Good to know! Ok, now what if I could get the whole NB-B cable with sheathing through a conduit and into the box? Sounds hard but just curious. I’d rather not have a junction box because (from what I understand) I’m not allowed to hide them behind drywall right? So I’d need an ugly access panel.

Comment: No need for an "ugly access panel". If you use a standard duplex box, a blank cover plate will fit just fine. You can paint/wallpaper it so it's visually less obvious if you desire, it just needs to have the screws visible and easily accessible. You _can_ pull cable through conduit, but it's A) harder to do, and B) requires larger conduit since the conduit must be sized off the wide dimension of the cable, not the flat dimension. If you search this site, you'll find lots of places where the minimum conduit size is spelled out for you.

Comment: I guess I could always hang a nice picture over it or something. Lol. 

Thank you sir.

Comment: Or for that matter, if the box is large enough for the 2 extra wires, you can put a receptacle there. The recep can't be on the dryer circuit, you'd need to pull 2 more wires to supply it.  (presuming all-metal EMT/Rigid back to the panel is serving as ground).

Comment: Yeah -- a receptacle is a very good disguise for such a transition box ;)

Comment: @TonySmith if Harper & TPE are making positive comments, you know that this is a good answer. They're the experts!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a kind of wire that needs conduit you could continue the conduit in EMT for the 20' to the outlet location. (replace the box immediately inside the wall with another LB body.)

If you want to transition to romex for the 20' to the outlet you'll need to use a box instead.